# Problema al comprobar roles y agregarlos a un div

Tags: javascript, web

Tengo un código bastante simple que lo que hace es comprobar si el usuario tiene los permisos guardados en el localstorage. Mi codigo es el siguiente:

```
  const permisosRoles = localStorage.getItem('userRoles');

const permisos = permisosRoles.split(',')

let option_roles = document.getElementById('modal_options2');

const motos = `<a class="btn btn-success"  href="../../../index.php" role="button"><i class="fas fa-motorcycle fa-3x"></i></a> `

const hogar = `<a class="btn btn-info"  href="../../../index_hogar.php" role="button"><i class="fas fa-laptop-house fa-3x"></i></a> `

const bikes = `<a class="btn btn-warning"  href="../../../index_bikes.php" role="button"><i class="fas fa-biking fa-3x"></i></a> `

const repuestos = `<a class="btn btn-dark"  href="../../../index_repuestos.php" role="button"><i class="fas fa-tools fa-3x" ></i></a> `



let permisosResult= '';

option_roles.style = "text-align:center";

console.log(permisosResult);

function changeIndicadores(){
  if(option_roles.innerHTML != null)
  {
    permisos.forEach(element => {
    if (element === 'Motos') {
        permisosResult += motos
    } else if (element === 'Hogar'){
        permisosResult += hogar
    } else if (element === 'Bikes'){
        permisosResult += bikes
    }else if (element === 'Repuestos'){
        permisosResult += repuestos
    };
    option_roles.innerHTML = permisosResult
    console.log(permisosResult);

}); 
  }
}
```

Funciona todo bien, el problema es que al hacer click se vuelven a agregar los botones a los que ya se agregaron anteriormente y así infinitamente. No se por que si cuando mando los botones compruebo que sea distinto de ' ', por que si ya agregué los botones entonces debería haber algo. Pero no me estaría funcionando de que otra forma podría hacerlo? Muchas Gracias!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deberias limpiar el contenido de `permisosResult` dentro de la funcion  `changeIndicadores`. Quedaria de esta forma:

```
const permisosRoles = localStorage.getItem('userRoles');

const permisos = permisosRoles.split(',')

let option_roles = document.getElementById('modal_options2');

const motos = `<a class="btn btn-success"  href="../../../index.php" role="button"><i class="fas fa-motorcycle fa-3x"></i></a> `

const hogar = `<a class="btn btn-info"  href="../../../index_hogar.php" role="button"><i class="fas fa-laptop-house fa-3x"></i></a> `

const bikes = `<a class="btn btn-warning"  href="../../../index_bikes.php" role="button"><i class="fas fa-biking fa-3x"></i></a> `

const repuestos = `<a class="btn btn-dark"  href="../../../index_repuestos.php" role="button"><i class="fas fa-tools fa-3x" ></i></a> `



let permisosResult= '';

option_roles.style = "text-align:center";

console.log(permisosResult);

function changeIndicadores(){
  if(option_roles.innerHTML != null)
  {
    permisosResult= ''; // Agregar esta linea
    permisos.forEach(element => {
    if (element === 'Motos') {
        permisosResult += motos
    } else if (element === 'Hogar'){
        permisosResult += hogar
    } else if (element === 'Bikes'){
        permisosResult += bikes
    }else if (element === 'Repuestos'){
        permisosResult += repuestos
    };
    option_roles.innerHTML = permisosResult
    console.log(permisosResult);

}); 
  }
}
```

Comment: Gracias! La verdad que es algo bastante simple. Hace tiempo hice algo parecido y lo pude solucionar. Pero no recordaba como lo había hecho. Gracias me funcionó perfecto esta solución.